# Dotnetnuke - pick which panes have HTML module in them on creation of new page

Tags: html, module, dotnetnuke, skin

Simpleton question:

I'm getting into DNN skinning, and I need to know how to have DNN pick the panes that the HTML module will appear in when a new page is created.

This way when I create new skins, I can have new page content appear where I want based on how I create the layout.

Thanks all!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default page template places an HTML module in the `ContentPane` of the skin.  However, you can also create other page templates, if you want different modules in other panes.

Answer (score 3):

In any skin file, the pane with the ID of "ContentPane" will be what receives the default page content.